# Long-form Pandas Dataframe from wide-form numpy arrays

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Suppose I have the following two numpy.ndarrays

1. pixels_array.shape = (1000, 28, 28)
2. labels_array.shape = (1000, 0)

Pixels_array is 1000 item array of 28 x 28 pixel values, and labels_array is simply a 1000 item list of labels for those pixel values. I am attempting to merge those arrays into a long-form dataframe that looks like (did not include array examples due to space):

| ID | Label | Pixels |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | 28x28 array |
| 2 | B | 28x28 array |
| 3 | Q | 28x28 array |
| 4 | 8 | 28x28 array |
| 5 | Z | 28x28 array |

What is the best way to do this? I have been messing with this about an hour and just cannot get melt to work the way I expect. Sometimes I get a row for each item in each array, other time I get a total of 2 rows. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do that with following.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Pixels': [pixels_array[i] for i in range(1000)],
                   'Label': labels_array.flatten()})
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Up until this point, I was using:

`mini_training_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Label', 'Pixels'], index=range(1000))
for i in range (1000):
  mini_training_df.loc[i].Label = labels_array[i]
  mini_training_df.loc[i].Pixels =  pixels_array[i]`

Comment: `list(pixels_array)` instead of the comprehension?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is rarely recommend, but one way is to coerce the array to a list first, i.e.:

```
arr1 = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(1000, 28, 28))                                                                                              
arr2 = np.random.randn(1000)                                                                                                                                                 
df = pd.Series(arr2, name="Label").to_frame()                                                                                                                                
df['pixels'] = arr1.tolist()
```

Then if you want you can convert it back to an array:

```
df.pixels = df.pixels.apply(np.array)
```

Output:

```
     Label                                             pixels
0 -0.187183  [[7, 9, 6, 5, 5, 7, 6, 9, 1, 7, 7, 7, 2, 8, 8,...
1  0.360777  [[1, 4, 6, 7, 7, 4, 9, 1, 1, 8, 8, 6, 9, 3, 6,...
2  0.206012  [[7, 4, 8, 3, 4, 3, 8, 9, 1, 9, 6, 8, 7, 5, 3,...
3  0.726619  [[1, 8, 8, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 8, 3, 6, 4, 1,...
4  0.801372  [[3, 5, 7, 3, 5, 7, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6, 3, 8, 5, 9,...
(...)
```

Comment: Why is this rarely recommended?

Comment: Having high dimension objects inside cells eventually become a challenge to handle. You might consider checking out `xarray` depending on your needs.